# Why won't hasNext() become false?

Tags: java, iterator, infinite-loop

From what I can see, if you have an iterable and you use iterable.hasNext inside of a loop it will loop through all of the elements inside of the array, but in the code here, it never terminates:

```
    //ArrayList<FriendlyBullet> list = . . .;
    Iterator<FriendlyBullet> fbi = list.iterator();
    while (fbi.hasNext()) { // This loops supposedly infinitely
        this.game.list.iterator().next().draw(g2d);
    }
```

I know there are not an infinite or a great amount items in the List. FriendlyBullet is just a class I am using. If there is something that I didn't include in my question that is essential for helping me, please tell me! I am not sure if this is a problem with my syntax or what, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This method call

```
this.game.list.iterator()....
```

creates a new iterator in each loop iteration. The `fbi.next()` never gets invoked.

You should reuse `fbi` as follows:

```
//ArrayList<FriendlyBullet> list = . . .;
Iterator<FriendlyBullet> fbi = list.iterator();
while (fbi.hasNext()) { // This loops supposedly infinitely
    fbi.next().draw(g2d);
}
```

Note that this happens to be equivalent to

```
for (FriendlyBullet fb : list)
    fb.draw(g2d);
```

or (if you're on Java 8)

```
list.forEach(fb -> fb.draw(g2d));
```

Comment: ... and therefore the `fbi` iterator is never advanced forward.

Comment: This makes sense, since I already declared game.list.iterator I don't need to refer to it again inside of the loop, I can use fbi instead. Also, Thank you for explaining for loops using (:) in this context because that is what I originally wanted to do but I didn't know how.